# How to insert multiple images uploaded in google form to google slides using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-slides

In google form, user are allowed to upload multiple images in one question like the following picture:
[image]

I want to display all of those uploaded images in google slides. I mean if the user upload one, two or three (or more) images then it will all be displayed in google slides. Is there any way to do that using google script?

Comment: About `I mean if the user upload one, two or three (or more) images then it will all be displayed in google slides. Is there any way to do that using google script?`, can you provide more information? 1. In your expected goal, when 2 images are uploaded, do you want to put them on 2 pages of Google Slides? 2. When more image is uploaded, do you want to append the images to the Google Slides? 3. Your script is the container-bound script of Google Form or Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: 4. In order to retrieve the uploaded files, it is required to know your Google Form. But from your showing image, I cannot understand your whole Form. For example, in your Google Form has only one question for uploading the multiple images?